# UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture() web request does not get a response from server, CORS issue maybe?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, download, cors, unitywebrequest

I have a Unity project where I'm trying to scrape images from websites but some of the URL's that I try to download images from don't work. So for example, if I try to use UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture() with this URL (https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1963/1339/files/G20-full-right-front.jpg) I'm able to download the image but if I use this URL
(https://pisces.bbystatic.com/image2/BestBuy_US/images/products/6427/6427116_sd.jpg) I get nothing

I've stepped through the code in a debugger and when I call www.SendWebRequest(); it never returns so I never get a HTTP error or a response.

Here is my code:

```
private IEnumerator LoadImage(string url)
   {
      using (var www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
      {
         yield return www.SendWebRequest();
         if (www.isNetworkError)
         {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
         }
         else
         {
         
            Texture2D texture = null;
            try
            {
               texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
 
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               Destroy(gameObject);
               yield break;
            }
 
            // do something with the texture
            ...
         }
      }
   }
```

I'm guessing there is some kind of CORS issue or else some kind of SSL cert issue. But I don't know what I could do to solve these issues.

Comment: I don't think it is failing silently .. only your implementation is. Which Unity version are you using? You should not only check `isNetworkError` but also [`isHttpError`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-isHttpError.html) .. you can also simply check `if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(www.error))` then whatever error is there it will be printed

Comment: When I send a request there is never a response from the server. When I call www.SendWebRequest(); it never returns so I never get a HTTP error. I've added more network checks but these checks never get called.